# Extend dimensions in netCDF file using R

Tags: r, netcdf

I would like to write a netCDF file using R with 'unlimited' dimensions that I can later extend.

This is what I have tried:

#### Create a netcdf file

```
library(ncdf4)

## define lat, lon time dimensions
lat <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_east", vals =  44.0, unlim = TRUE) 
lon <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_north", vals = -88.5, unlim = TRUE)
time <- ncdim_def("time", "days since 0000-01-01", 1:1000)

## define data with these dimensions
x <- ncvar_def("myvar", units = "m2", dim = list(lat, lon, time))

## create, write to, close nc file
nc <- nc_create(filename = "tmp.nc", vars = list(x))

ncvar_put(nc = nc, varid = x, vals = 1:1000)
nc_close(nc = nc)
```

#### I want to add a new vector at a different lat and lon

```
## reopen existing file
nc <- nc_open("tmp.nc", write = TRUE)

## define new lat, lon dimensions (keep time dim from above)
lat2 <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_east", vals =  44.5, unlim = TRUE) 
lon2 <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_north", vals = -89.0, unlim = TRUE)

## define, write new dataset at new lat lon coordinates
x2 <- ncvar_def("myvar", units = "m2", dim = list(lat2, lon2, time))
ncvar_put(nc = nc, varid = x2, vals = 11:1011)
```

#### I would expect to find the two different latitudes and longitudes

```
ncvar_get(nc, 'latitude')
ncvar_get(nc, 'longitude')

ncvar_get(nc, 'myvar')
```

These show that the file was written using the first set of lat/lon and 'myvar' values, but was not appended with the new set of values.

#### What am I doing wrong?

I know that the ability to have multiple unlimited dimensions, and to add to them, is a feature of netCDF-4. How can I do this in R?

I recognize that I must be confusing the 'dimension definition' with some other concept. But I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think you are confusing the 'dimension definition' and the actual data within the dimension variable.

If you run your first snippet of code and then dump the NetCDF file using `ncdump`, you'll see:

```
netcdf tmp {
dimensions:
        latitude = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
        longitude = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
        time = 1000 ;
variables:
        double latitude(latitude) ;
                latitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
                latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
        double longitude(longitude) ;
                longitude:units = "degrees_north" ;
                longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
        int time(time) ;
                time:units = "days since 0000-01-01" ;
                time:long_name = "time" ;
        float myvar(time, longitude, latitude) ;
                myvar:units = "m2" ;
data:

 latitude = 44 ;

 longitude = -88.5 ;

 time = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
    ...
    990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999, 1000 ;

 myvar =
  {{1}},
  {{2}},
  {{3}},
  ...
  {{1000}} ;
}
```

The dimensions are saying `latitude` and `longitude` are unlimited while the `time` dimension is fixed at 1000 points/days since 0000-01-01. This is exactly what you specified, which is good.

So to add another latitude and longitude. I would open the file again, read in the current data, append to it and then write it back.

```
library(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open("tmp.nc", write = TRUE)
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid='latitude')
lat <- append(lat, 44.5)
ncvar_put(nc, varid='latitude', vals=lat, start=c(1), count=2)
nc_close(nc)
```

Now `ncdump` will show you two latitudes:

```
data:

 latitude = 44, 44.5 ;

 longitude = -88.5 ;
```

Of course for large datasets you do not need or want to read in all the data and the append, you can just tell NetCDF where you want it written.

```
library(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open("tmp.nc", write = TRUE)
lon = -89.0
ncvar_put(nc, varid='longitude', vals=lon, start=c(2), count=1)
nc_close(nc)
```

Now `ncdump` will show you two latitudes and two longitudes:

```
data:

 latitude = 44, 44.5 ;

 longitude = -88.5, -89 ;
```

The data represents of `myvar` is a 3D array, so I would have done the initial write different. I would have specified it's dimensions when creating the data and when writing it to the file, like this:

```
data <- array(1:1000, c(1,1,1000))
ncvar_put(nc = nc, varid='myvar', vals=data, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(1,1,1000))
```

Then to append to the second latitude and longitude:

```
data <- array(11:1011, c(1,1,1000))
ncvar_put(nc = nc, varid='myvar', vals=data, start=c(2,2,1), count=c(1,1,1000))
```

---

**NOTE**

I feel the R package hides too much from you. When you create a dimension with `ncdim_def`, you can give it values. This is in my mind more of a 3 step process.

1. Create the dimension.
2. Create a variable associated with that dimension.
3. Add data to this variable.

Hope this helps.